# Javascript changing an array[i] depending on an if statement then concatenating it every time the function is run

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Im trying to append an array within an if statement so that the next time the function is run the array.length has increased giving a different result. My problem is that the for loop is dependent on the result of the if statement. i.e if the requirements are met the array.length will increase by one. However the only way I know how to do this is place the for loop within the if statement which basically makes the `var i = 0` everytime the function starts. Im thinking I need to do something to i outside the if statement.

```
    //setting a loop or rather interval
function hRandom() {
        var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById("head").style.color=getRandomColor();
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            }, 180000);
        }


var clickedTime; var createdTime;

Date.now();

function makebox() {

    var time=Math.random();

    time=time*5000;

    setTimeout(function() {

    if (Math.random()>0.5) {
    document.getElementById("redBox").style.borderRadius = "50%";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("redBox").style.borderRadius ="0";
    }

    var top=Math.random();

    top=top*300;

    var left=Math.random();

    left=left*600;

    document.getElementById("redBox").style.top=top+"px";
    document.getElementById("redBox").style.left=left+"px";

    document.getElementById("redBox").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    document.getElementById("redBox").style.display = "block";
    createdTime=Date.now();
    }, time);
}

document.getElementById("redBox").onclick = function() {

    clickedTime=Date.now();

    reactionTime=(clickedTime-createdTime)/1000;

    var rt = parseFloat(reactionTime);

    var about = new Array();

    about[0]="Statement one"
    about[1]="Statement two";
    about[2]="Statement three";

    if (rt < 0.5) 
    for (var i =0; i < about.length; i++) {document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = about[i];} 
    else {document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "TOO SLOW!";}

    document.getElementById("yourTime").innerHTML=reactionTime+"s";


    this.style.display = "none";
    makebox();

}

makebox();
hRandom();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. Will that make the i within the function a different i. Sorry If my questions are dumb, I havent been doing javascript for a long time and ive looked everywhere but cant seem to get the result i want.

Comment: just tel me what is your point exactly ? and ill be glad to assist you

Comment: Basically I want  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = about[i] and about[i] to i++ each time the if statement is met. so that each time the about[i] is a different array until they have cycled through all the arrays

Comment: You wrote `for(..){..}else{..}`. Check that.

Comment: _BTW_: You have wrong syntax: `for (var i =0; i < about.length; i++) {document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = about[i];} else {document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "TOO SLOW!";}`

Comment: the javascrip works however instead of the document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = about[i]; and changing each time the function is run i keep getting the innerHTML saying "statement one" over and over again instead of cycling through the arrays. :(

Comment: Because you did not close your `for` loop as @hindmost and I mentioned it. And even if you do close it, the loop will be too fast and you will only be able to read "statement three". You should use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` if you want them to be displayed one after the other.

Comment: Thanks for that I changed the syntax but it still only shows the same array over and over again, I thought that by increasing i each time the if statement is met then i would be able to display each array in an ascending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to move anything that needs to track state across invocations of your click handler outside of that function.

For example (with values changed to make it easier to trigger the logic):

```
var createdTime = Date.now();
var about = ["Statement one", "Statement two", "Statement three"];
var aboutIdx = 0;

document.getElementById("redBox").onclick = function () {

    clickedTime = Date.now();

    reactionTime = (clickedTime - createdTime) / 1000;

    var rt = parseFloat(reactionTime);


    if (rt < 10.5) {
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = about[aboutIdx++ % about.length];
    } else {
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "TOO SLOW!";
    }

    document.getElementById("yourTime").innerHTML = reactionTime + "s";
};
```

Here, instead of looping through `about`, I'm referencing an externally scoped `aboutIdx` variable that tracks the number of times the click handler is called.  [Modulo (%)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) that against the length of of the about array will give you an index of 0, 1 or 2 depending on the value of `aboutIdx`.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1ov6psjr/)

Comment: so [aboutIdx++ % about.length]; will basically make var aboutIdx = 1 then the next time the if statement is met aboutIdx = 2?

Comment: correct - if you run the fiddle and click multiple times on the button, you will see the value cycle through.

Comment: Thanks @dc5 that's the code and everything, really really appreciate mate. I've only been doing javascript for about a week and im still trying to get my head around it all. This really helped!!!

Comment: what does % mean in about[aboutIdx++ % about.length];

Comment: It is the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) - gives the remainder  of the first value divided by the second.

Comment: I get it now, took me a while to wrap my head around what it was doing. Thanks again man.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the if statement and your loop , i don't know what is the value of the rest of your function variables so i made it simple .

I've made simple javascript as your request check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/thdnjrk8/2/

```
    var about = [ {"num": 0.3 , "text":"Statement one"}, 
                  {"num": 0.5 , "text":"Statement two"},
                  {"num": 0.8 , "text":"Statement three"}];


    document.getElementById("redBox").onclick = function() {

var rt = 0.3;

        for (var i =0; i < about.length; i++) 
        {
             if ( about[i].num > rt   )
             {
               document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = about[i].text; 
                 break;
             }

        } 

    }
```

Comment: sorry this is the whole code. its a reaction game. The link to it is here maybe you'll get a better idea of what im trying to achieve. The only part I cant seem to get to work is the array loop down the bottom.

Comment: but your condition has mess understanding , `if (rt < 0.5)` 0.5 is static so if rt is less than 0.5 the `para` value will be always last element inside `about` array , because you don't have condition inside your loop `for` you have to put a condition inside the loop to fix your problem

Comment: the problem is I cant make the array dependent on different values, I was trying to find a way to move the index each time the if statement is met so that the information is different each time as long as rt <0.5

Comment: so put the array outside the function make it stand alone , and you can add more values to array by using `about.push("another value");`